# How do I alter a trigger in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, alter, database-trigger

I am trying to change the trigger script for my database. My trigger name is `ARCH_USER_UPD_TRG` and this puts any updates or deletes on the `USER` table into a `Z_USER` table

I am dropping a column from the `USER` table and now need to modify the trigger script to no longer use this column.

How do I modify the PL/SQL script of an oracle trigger?

Comment: `create or replace trigger ARCH_USER_UPD_TRG` ?

Comment: [ALTER TRIGGER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4001.htm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A trigger is similar to a package or a procedure, so you can simply use

```
create or replace trigger triggerName
...
declare
...
begin
    ...
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution would be to [`Drop`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/drop_trigger.htm) and [`Create`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) the trigger once again with the modified SQL script code.

```
DROP TRIGGER ARCH_USER_UPD_TRG; 

CREATE TRIGGER ARCH_USER_UPD_TRG
//rest of code body
```

Comment: There is no need to drop and recreate, you can simply do "create or replace"